# How can I cluster a list of a list of tuple (tag, probability)? - python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a bunch of text and they are classified into categories and then each document is tagged 0, 1 or 2 with a probability for each tag.

```
[ "this is a foo bar",
  "bar bar black sheep",
  "sheep is an animal"
  "foo foo bar bar"
  "bar bar sheep sheep" ]
```

The previous tool in the pipeline returns a list of list of tuples as such, each element in the outer list is sort of a document. I can only work with the fact that I know each documents are tagged 0, 1 or 2 and their probabilities as such:

```
[ [(0,0.3), (1,0.5), (2,0.1)],
  [(0,0.5), (1,0.3), (2,0.3)],
  [(0,0.4), (1,0.4), (2,0.5)],
  [(0,0.3), (1,0.7), (2,0.2)],
  [(0,0.2), (1,0.6), (2,0.1)] ]
```

I need it to see which tag each of the list of tuple is most probable and achieve:

```
[ [[(0,0.5), (1,0.3), (2,0.3)], [(0,0.4), (1,0.4), (2,0.5)]] ,
  [[(0,0.3), (1,0.7), (2,0.2)], [(0,0.2), (1,0.6), (2,0.1)]] ,
  [[(0,0.4), (1,0.4), (2,0.5)]] ]
```

As another example:

`[in]`:

```
[ [(0,0.7), (1,0.2), (2,0.4)],
  [(0,0.5), (1,0.9), (2,0.3)],
  [(0,0.3), (1,0.8), (2,0.4)],
  [(0,0.8), (1,0.2), (2,0.2)],
  [(0,0.1), (1,0.7), (2,0.5)] ]
```

`[out]`:

```
 [[[(0,0.7), (1,0.2), (2,0.4)],
 [(0,0.8), (1,0.2), (2,0.2)]] ,

 [[(0,0.5), (1,0.9), (2,0.3)],
 [(0,0.1), (1,0.7), (2,0.5)],
 [(0,0.3), (1,0.8), (2,0.4)]] ,

 []]
```

**NOTE:** I do **NOT** have access to the original text when the data comes to my part of the pipeline.

How can I cluster a list of a list of tuple with tags and probability? Is there something in `numpy`, `scipy`, `sklearn` or any python-able ML suite to do that? or even `NLTK`.

Let's take it that the number of cluster is fixed but cluster size is not.

I've only tried finding maximum value of the centroid but that only gives me the first value in each cluster:

```
instream = [ [(0,0.3), (1,0.5), (2,0.1)],
                        [(0,0.5), (1,0.3), (2,0.3)],
                        [(0,0.4), (1,0.4), (2,0.5)],
                        [(0,0.3), (1,0.7), (2,0.2)],
                        [(0,0.2), (1,0.6), (2,0.1)] ]

# Find centroid.  
c1_centroid_value = sorted([i[0] for i in instream], reverse=True)[0]
c2_centroid_value = sorted([i[1] for i in instream], reverse=True)[0]
c3_centroid_value = sorted([i[2] for i in instream], reverse=True)[0]

c1_centroid = [i for i,j in enumerate(instream) if j[0] == c1_centroid_value][0]
c2_centroid = [i for i,j in enumerate(instream) if j[1] == c2_centroid_value][0]
c3_centroid = [i for i,j in enumerate(instream) if j[2] == c3_centroid_value][0]

print instream[c1_centroid]
print instream[c2_centroid]
print instream[c2_centroid]
```

`[out]` (top element in each cluster:

```
[(0, 0.5), (1, 0.3), (2, 0.3)]
[(0, 0.3), (1, 0.7), (2, 0.2)]
[(0, 0.3), (1, 0.7), (2, 0.2)]
```

Comment: It would help if you could show an example of some input/output. And just more explanation of what exactly you are trying to do, also - make sure its's not an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @InbarRose, I've edited the question to give some more background.

Comment: Shouldn't the third line in you `out` be `[(0,0.4), (1,0.4), (2,0.5)]` ?

Comment: typo and it's a list of list output but that's easily manipulable =)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your input is a list of lists of tuples. Each inner list has 3 tuples which each have 2 items, the first item will be either 0,1, or 2. and the second item is the probability (a float) You want to get the lists that correspond with the maximum probability of each of the first items (0,1, and 2) of the tuples?

Comment: not the maximum but clustering the inner list such that they group into 3 groups.

Comment: I don't know what that means - can you please give *several* examples of input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you wanted.

```
import numpy as np

N_TYPES = 3

instream = [ [(0,0.3), (1,0.5), (2,0.1)],
             [(0,0.5), (1,0.3), (2,0.3)],
             [(0,0.4), (1,0.4), (2,0.5)],
             [(0,0.3), (1,0.7), (2,0.2)],
             [(0,0.2), (1,0.6), (2,0.1)] ]
instream = np.array(instream)

# this removes document tags because we only consider probabilities here
values = [map(lambda x: x[1], doc) for doc in instream]

# determine the cluster of each document by using maximum probability
belongs_to = map(lambda x: np.argmax(x), values)
belongs_to = np.array(belongs_to)

# construct clusters of indices to your instream
cluster_indices = [(belongs_to == k).nonzero()[0] for k in range(N_TYPES)]

# apply the indices to obtain full output
out = [instream[cluster_indices[k]].tolist() for k in range(N_TYPES)]
```

output `out`:

```
[[[[0.0, 0.5], [1.0, 0.3], [2.0, 0.3]]],

 [[[0.0, 0.3], [1.0, 0.5], [2.0, 0.1]],
  [[0.0, 0.3], [1.0, 0.7], [2.0, 0.2]],
  [[0.0, 0.2], [1.0, 0.6], [2.0, 0.1]]],

 [[[0.0, 0.4], [1.0, 0.4], [2.0, 0.5]]]]
```

I used `numpy` arrays because they enable nice searching and indexing. For example, the expression `(belongs_to == 1).nonzero()[0]` returns the array of indices to array `belongs_to` where the value is `1`. Example of indexing is `instream[cluster_indices[2]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep the indices in the tuples? the `0`, `1` and `2` are redundant and don't provide any information if I understand you correctly. Just provide the `n_samples x 3` array of probabilities to any scikit-learn algorithm.
Or if you just want the most likely label assignment, do an `np.argmax(X, axis=1)`.