# Python: Brown Clustering in NLTK or other package?

Tags: python, package, cluster-analysis, nltk

Simple Question: Is the Brown Clustering Technique (not the trained model) part of NLTK or another package that can be easily installed on Windows?

[Wikipedia: Brown Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_clustering)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this Q&A [What does the Brown clustering algorithm output mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998832/what-does-the-brown-clustering-algorithm-output-mean)  @alvas gives the link to a python implementation

I wish I could give a more definitive answer, but it does not look to be part of NLTK.  The only clustering algorithms I see are here: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.cluster.html

Brown clustering is a type of hierarchical clustering as your wiki link indicates, so general hierarchical clustering may help you from scikit:  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering

Answer (score 0):

I found the most feasible way to use Brown Clustetr(not the model but the corpus) is made by CMU Tweet NLP
http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/

They built Twitter Word Clusters based on  Percy Liang's Brown clustering implementation on Lui and Baldwin's langid.py-identified English tweets. 
By some simple map-reduce work, you can easily implement your brown cluster to your text.