# How do I print lda topic model and the word cloud of each of the topics

Tags: python, topic-modeling, word-cloud

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from stop_words import get_stop_words
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim
import os
from os import path
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
en_stop = set(get_stop_words('en'))
with open(os.path.join('c:\users\kaila\jobdescription.txt')) as f:
    Reader = f.read()

Reader = Reader.replace("will", " ")
Reader = Reader.replace("please", " ")


texts = unicode(Reader, errors='replace')
tdm = []

raw = texts.lower()
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in en_stop]
tdm.append(stopped_tokens)

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tdm)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(i) for i in tdm]
sleep(3)
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=8, id2word = dictionary)
topics = ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=8, num_words=200)
for i in topics:
    print(i)
    wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(i)
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
```

The issue is with the word cloud. I cannot get the word cloud for each of the 8 topics. I would want an output which gives 8 word clouds for the 8 topics. 
If anyone can help me regarding this issue, it will be great.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have trained a gensim lda model you can simply create a word cloud with the following code

```
# lda is assumed to be the variable holding the LdaModel object
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for t in range(lda.num_topics):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(lda.show_topic(t, 200)))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("Topic #" + str(t))
    plt.show()
```

I will highlight a few mistakes on your code so you can better follow what I have written above.

`WordCloud().generate(something)` expects *something* to be raw text. It will tokenize it, lowercase it and remove stop words and then compute the word cloud. You need the word sizes to match their probability in a topic (I assume).

`lda.print_topics(8, 200)` returns a textual representation of the topics as in `prob1*"token1" + prob2*"token2" + ...` you need the `lda.show_topic(topic, num_words)` to get the word with the corresponding probability as tuples. Then you need `WordCloud().fit_words()` to generate the word cloud.

The following code is your code with the above visualization. I would also like to point out that you are inferring topics from a single document which is very uncommon and probably not what you wanted.

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from stop_words import get_stop_words
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim
import os
from os import path
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
en_stop = set(get_stop_words('en'))
with open(os.path.join('c:\users\kaila\jobdescription.txt')) as f:
    Reader = f.read()

Reader = Reader.replace("will", " ")
Reader = Reader.replace("please", " ")


texts = unicode(Reader, errors='replace')
tdm = []

raw = texts.lower()
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in en_stop]
tdm.append(stopped_tokens)

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tdm)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(i) for i in tdm]
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=8, id2word = dictionary)
for t in range(ldamodel.num_topics):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(ldamodel.show_topic(t, 200)))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("Topic #" + str(t))
    plt.show()
```

Although from a different library you can see [topic visualizations with corresponding code](http://ldaplusplus.com/topic-inference-visualization/) for what the result will be (Disclaimer: I am on of the authors of that library).

Comment: Thanks alot. That certainly solved my problem. I am sorry I cannot upvote as of now as I have not gained the reputation to do so

Comment: I have actually scraped the jobsdb data and used it for analysis. The scraped data is compiled under one file which was used for topic modelling.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, in the latest version of wordcloud, `fit_words` takes a dict, whereas `lda.show_topic` returns a list of tuples. I had to use the line `plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(dict(lda.show_topic(t, 200))))` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:
First, create a lda model and define clusters/topics as discussed in [Topic Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984841/topic-distribution-how-do-we-see-which-document-belong-to-which-topic-after-doi/) - Make sure the minimum_probability is 0.
Next, determine the LDA corpus using `lda_corpus = lda[corpus]`
Now identify the documents from the data belonging to each Topic as a list, below example has two topics. df is my raw data that has a column texts

```
cluster1 = [j for i,j in zip(lda_corpus,df.texts) if i[0][1] > .2]
cluster2 = [j for i,j in zip(lda_corpus,df.texts) if i[1][1] > .2]
```

Obtain the Word Cloud for each cluster. You can include as many stop words as we can. Make sure to clean the data in the cluster like remove stopwords, stemming etc. I am skipping those steps, so that each cluster will have cleaned texts/documents.

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(relative_scaling = 1.0, stopwords=("xxx", 'yyy').generate(' '. join(cluster1))
```

Finally Plot word cloud using matplotlib

```
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
```