# How to generate word clouds from LDA models in Python?

Tags: python, lda, word-cloud

I am doing some topic modeling on newspaper articles, and have implemented LDA using gensim in Python3. Now I want to create a word cloud for each topic, using the top 20 words for each topic. I know I can print the words, and save the LDA model, but is there any way to just save the top words for each topic which I can further use for generating word clouds?

I tried to google it, but could not find anything relevant. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @JulienBernu Yes I have. The model object has attributes for topics, not the words for each topic. There is no conceptual difficulty, I just don't know how to extract those words to another variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the topn words from an LDA model using Gensim's built-in method show_topic.

```
lda = models.LdaModel.load('lda.model')

for i in range(0, lda.num_topics):
    with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write('{}\n'.format('Topic #' + str(i + 1) + ': '))
        for word, prob in lda.show_topic(i, topn=20):
            outfile.write('{}\n'.format(word.encode('utf-8')))
        outfile.write('\n')
```

This will write a file with a format similar to this:

```
Topic #69: 
pet
dental
tooth
adopt
animal
puppy
rescue
dentist
adoption
animal
shelter
pet
dentistry
vet
paw
pup
patient
mix
foster
owner

Topic #70: 
periscope
disneyland
disney
snapchat
brandon
britney
periscope
periscope
replay
britneyspear
buffaloexchange
britneyspear
https
meerkat
blab
periscope
kxci
toni
disneyland
location
```

You may or may not need to adjust this to your needs, ie yield a list of top 20 words instead of outputting it to a text file.

The answer in this post gives a good explanation of how to use raw text to create the word clouds.
[How do I print lda topic model and the word cloud of each of the topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278023/how-do-i-print-lda-topic-model-and-the-word-cloud-of-each-of-the-topics/40282878#40282878)

Comment: hi i tried the above codes it works just that i not sure y is my output has a "b" in at the beginning ... please look at the below output

Comment: Topic #5
b'barrier'
b'parenteral'
b'short'
b'salt'
b'influenza'
b'resume'
b'vital'
b'taken'
b'turning'
b'decrease'
b'baseline'
b'cardiac'
b'left'
b'insitu'
b'place'
b'supervision'

Answer (score 0):

is there any way to just save the top words for each topic ?

Yes there is. [jLDADMM](http://jldadmm.sourceforge.net/) outputs the top topical words for each topic. In [version 1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jldadmm/files/), only top topical words are written in the top-word output file, without their probabilities given the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using [pyldavis](https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#usage) package which can be used to visualize LDA models generated through [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/). An example is shown [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/notebooks/pyLDAvis_overview.ipynb#topic=0&lambda=1&term=)