# How to create wordcloud from LDA model?

Tags: python-3.x, lda, word-cloud

Following the documentation of `?gensim.models.ldamodel`, I want to train an `ldamodel` and (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282878/8839068) SO answer create a worcloud from it). I am using the following code from both sources:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
import gensim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

common_dictionary = Dictionary(common_texts) # create corpus
common_corpus = [common_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in common_texts]

lda = gensim.models.LdaModel(common_corpus, num_topics=10) # train model on corpus
for t in range(lda.num_topics):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(lda.show_topic(t, 200)))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("Topic #" + str(t))
    plt.show()
```

However, I get an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'` on the line `plt.imshow(...)`

Can someone help me out here? (Answers to similar questions have not been working for me and I am trying to compile a minimal pipeline with this.)

Comment: How does `lda.show_topic(t, 200)` look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs, the method [`WordCloud.fit_words()`](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html?highlight=fit_words#wordcloud.WordCloud.fit_words) expects a dictionary as input.

Your error seems to highlight that it's looking for an attribute `'items'`, typically an attribute of dictionaries, but instead finds a `list` object.

So the problem is: `lda.show_topic(t, 200)` returns a list instead of a dictionary. Use `dict()` to cast it!

Finally:

```
plt.imshow(WordCloud().fit_words(dict(lda.show_topic(t, 200))))
```