# Document clustering: DBSCAN and optics clustering not giving me any clusters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki

I tried doing DBSCAN clustering using word2vec weighted tfidf vectors and used different thresholds of epsilon and minpts for DBSCAN. I also tried optics clustering method with different minpts, however it didn't yield any output at all.

```
#Import libraries
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from unidecode import unidecode # $ pip install unidecode
import gensim
import csv
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from string import lower

#read data
dat = pd.read_csv('D:\\data_800k.csv',encoding='latin',nrows=500000).Certi.tolist()

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
#nltk.download('punkt')
my_stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDSunion(['education','certification','certificate','certified'])


def tokenize_stop(row):
    az = []
    for j in nltk.word_tokenize(lower(unidecode(row))):
        if j not in my_stop_words:
            az.extend([j])
    return az

def preprocess(dat):
    return [tokenize_stop(row) for row in dat]


X = preprocess(dat)

#word2vec
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(X, size=100)
w2v = dict(zip(model.wv.index2word, model.wv.syn0))


#
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x)
tfidf.fit(X)
max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)

#train model
def fit(X):
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x)
    tfidf.fit(X)
    # if a word was never seen - it must be at least as infrequent
    # as any of the known words - so the default idf is the max of 
    # known idf's
    max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)
    return defaultdict(
        lambda: max_idf,
        [(w, tfidf.idf_[i]) for w, i in tfidf.vocabulary_.items()])

#actual training//
word2weight = fit(X)

#multiply word2vec with tfidf
def transform_word2vec_tfidf(X,word2vec,word2weight):
    return np.array([
            np.mean([word2vec[w] * word2weight[w]
                     for w in words if w in word2vec] or
                    [np.zeros(dim)], axis=0)
            for words in X
        ])


export_data_w2v_Tfidf = transform_word2vec_tfidf(X,w2v,word2weight)
np.savetxt('D:\Azim\data_500k_w2v_tfidf.csv',export_data_w2v_Tfidf,delimiter=',',fmt=('%1.15e'))
```

Below is ELKI screenshot. Can anyone share insights f they were able to do meaningful clustering of text data using DBSCAN or any other algorithm? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you try a larger Epsilon? A kdist plot? An OPTICS plot?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes, at larger epsilon it will run out of memory. Same with optics

Comment: Experiment with a subset first. No need to solve scalability before finding the correct *way*.

Comment: I did for 50000 documents, and then tried using the epsilon value for the entire dataset. Results in this stackoverflow.com question is for the entire data.

Comment: Also, the minpts value is way too high.

Comment: Minpts is based on business logic. It cannot be lesser than that

Comment: Do not misinterpret minPts as minimum cluster size!

Comment: What is it then? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88891/68444

Comment: A density threshold. The clusters found are usually much larger. For example on the Iris data, one would use minpts=4, although the clusters you want to find are 50 to 100 objects. If you don't want small clusters, you can still skip them in the next step.

Comment: In case of smaller minpts it takes forever and ends with memoryerror.

Comment: Try a smaller sample again. And of course don't go all the way down to 4 immediately. There are suggestions for the values to try, and by looking at knn distance plots, you don't need to run it for the entire data every time.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think DBSCAN is a promising method for text data. Choosing the parameters will be difficult (but as noted in the comments, your minpts is likely *much* too large), and apparently you are hitting scalability problems, too. I am also not sure what effect your "word2vec" in there has. word2vec may make things much more difficult here.

I'd rather go with LDA. That is usually the best method for text.

When you use OPTICS, beware that OPTICS will not produce *partitions*. It produces the optics *plot*. You need e.g. the Xi method to extract partitions, and that adds another parameter that may be difficult to choose in high dimensional data.

Comment: Can you suggest a good clustering method for text, apart from Lda? I tried using Lda and facing issues there as well, because Lda is not giving any hard clusters. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49380258/4566277

Comment: Yes, LDA gives soft clustering. With text data, you *need* soft clustering for best results.