# Gensim: extract 100 most representative documents for each topic

Tags: python, tuples, gensim, lda

I have several gensim models fit to ~5 million documents. I'd like to pull the top 100 most representative documents from each of models for each topic to help me pick the best model.

Let's say I have a model `lda` and corpus `corpus`, I can get the topic probabilities in the following form:

```
topic_probs = lda[corpus]
```

Where `topic_probs` is a list of tuples: `(topic_num, topic_prob)`.

How can I sort this list of tuples by topic, and then probability, then retrieve the top 100 documents from the corpus? I'm guessing the answer looks something like the [method for assigning topics here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984841/topic-distribution-how-do-we-see-which-document-belong-to-which-topic-after-doi), but I'm struggling with how to work with a list of tuples while maintaining the document indices.

(This is somewhat complicated by the fact that I didn't know about the `minimum_probability` argument to `gensim.LdaModel`, so topics with < 0.01 probability are suppressed. These models take 2-3 days to run each, so I'd like to avoid re-running them if possible).

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to figure this out, though possibly not in the most efficient way possible, and I didn't have time to make it fully portable.

1. I extract the by-document topic probabilities, and dump it to csv (my corpus is large and takes forever to process, so I wanted to have these saved). You can easily loop this over multiple models.

```
def lda_to_csv(model, outfile, corpus):
    '''This function takes a gensim lda model as input, and outputs a csv with topics probs by document'''
    topic_probs = model.get_document_topics(corpus) #get the list of topic probabilities by doc
    topic_dict = [dict(x) for x in topic_probs] #convert to dictionary to convert to data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame(topic_dict).fillna(0) #convert to data frame, fill topics < 0.01 as 0
    df.to_csv(outfile)
```

2. Wrote a function that selects the n-largest probabilities for each topic, then extracts and returns the document given the original (not BoW) texts as a list. This assumes the column with document indices is named "docs". The data frame is the one created by the previous function, read back in from csv.

```
def get_best_docs(df, n, k, texts):
    '''Return the index of the n most representative documents from a list of topic responsibilities for each topic'''
    '''n is the number of douments you want, k is the number of topics in the model, the texts are the FULL texts used to fit the model'''
    #create column list to iterate over
    k_cols = range(0, k)

    #intialize empty list to hold results
    n_rep_docs = []

    #loop to extract documents for each topic
    for i in k_cols:
        inds = df.nlargest(n = n, columns = str(i))['docs'].astype(int).tolist()
        #use list comprehension to extract documents
        n_rep_docs.append([texts[ind] for ind in inds])

    return n_rep_docs
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to alert others who may find themselves on this page that I believe the code posted previously is incorrect. I haven't had time to locate the exact source of the error, but I used it in my work for a few weeks and obtained very jumbled results. The documents assigned as "top candidates" for each topic were incoherent and did not correspond with the topic's representative words. I recently started using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777101/topic-wise-document-distribution-in-gensim-lda) instead and have obtained much more coherent results.